# Error when using HTTParty gem to consume API: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5, httparty

I keep getting this error: **"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"** while trying to parse JSON using HTTParty in Ruby on Rails.

I want to be able to consume an API, but am unable to get anything to work.

The URL works fine and returns JSON elements with no problem; I am just unable to access them and present them for some strange reason.

I am using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4. All API keys are hidden, but are properly input into my Rails app.

**Here is my lib file:**

```
require 'httparty'

class Wunderground
  include HTTParty
  format :json

  base_uri 'api.wunderground.com'

  attr_accessor :temp, :location, :icon, :desc, :url, :feel_like

  def initialize(response)
    @temp = response['current_observation']['temp_f']
    @location = response['current_observation']['display_location']['full']
    @icon = response['current_observation']['icon_url']
    @desc = response['current_observation']['weather']
    @url = response['current_observation']['forecast_url']
    @feel_like = response['current_observation']['feelslike_f']
  end

  def self.get_weather(state, city)
    response = get("/api/#{ENV["wunderground_key"]}/conditions/q/#{state}/#{city}.json")
    if response.success?
      new(response)
    else
      raise response.response
    end
  end

end
```

I've entered **my api key** into my application.yml file like so:

```
wunderground_key: "YOUR_API_KEY"
```

**My controller:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  require 'Wunderground'

  def wunderground
    @weather = Wunderground.get_weather(params[:state], params[:city])
  end

  def index
  end
end
```

**My routes:**

```
  root 'home#index'

  get 'wunderground', to: 'home#wunderground'
```

**My view:**

```html
<div>
    <%= form_tag wunderground_path, method: "get", class: "form-inline" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :city, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "City Name" %>
    <%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(@states), :prompt => "Please select", class: "form-control" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Check Weather", name: nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div>
<% if @weather.present? %>
  <h3><%= @weather.location %></h3>

  <p>The temperature is:
    <%= @weather.temp %></p>
  <p>Feels like:
    <%= @weather.feel_like %></p>

  <p>
    <%= @weather.desc %>
    <%= image_tag @weather.icon %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%=link_to "Full Forecast", @weather.url, target: "_blank" %>
  </p>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**Edit:**

This is the error that I am getting as shown in the development log:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
lib/Wunderground.rb:12:in `initialize'
lib/Wunderground.rb:23:in `new'
lib/Wunderground.rb:23:in `get_weather'
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:6:in `wunderground'
```

Comment: Post the full error log and the value in the `response` variable in `get_weather` method.

Comment: Edited to reflect the full error shown in the development log. "Response" is what the Wunderground API returns upon accessing the API.

Comment: I think `response` or `response['current_observation']` is `nil`. Thats why you receive this error. It would be easy to find the cause if you post the value of `response` variable.

Answer (score 3):

### Source of error

You're getting this error, because `response['current_observation']` is nil.

### Debugging strategy

To arrive at this conclusion, we typically look at the error message, and the line of code the error is originating from.

From your question, it's clear that you already know what the error is:  `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`, and if you look at the stack trace, your error is coming from `lib/Wunderground.rb:12:in initialize'`.

The relevant line of code is this:

```
@temp = response['current_observation']['temp_f']
```

In Ruby, `object['foo']` is a syntax sugar for the "call the `[]` method on `object` with argument `'foo'`.  It can also be described as "send `[]` message to `object` with an argument `'foo'`.

Chained `[][]` calls are just calling the same method on the returned object.

In effect, you are calling `[]` with `'current_observation'` on `response`, and then calling `[]` on the returned object with `'temp_f'`.  What this means, is that you're calling `[]` on 2 objects:

1. `response`
2. Object returned by `response['current_observation']`

Looking at the error, `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`, tells us that one of the above two objects is nil.

Since in a previous call `response.success?` returned `true`, we can conclude `response['current_observation']` is indeed returning nil.

### Further debugging and finding ways to fix this

There are a few options.

1. Pretty print the response: `pp response.parsed_response`.
2. Use the `debug_output` setting from HTTParty to look at the HTTP request response log.

   ```
   class Wunderground
     include HTTParty
     format :json
     debug_output $stdout

     # ...
     # rest of the code
     # ...
   end
   ```

With debug mode on, watch the server log so you can get an idea about what response is the API returning.